# Jquery load callback doesn't fire when something is actually loaded

Tags: jquery

I just moved to jquery 1.11.1 (i was on 1.2.x before on this project).  The $.load function used to pull response text/html into an element doesn't appear to be firing the callback all of sudden!

```
$("#thing").load("page", null, callback);
```

So i debugged the jquery code.. as expected it uses $.ajax, grabs a page, puls it in the self using $.html and then the callback is actually fired on the "complete" function of $.ajax.  This function is meant to always fire at all times, whether the ajax was successful or not.  After driving myself INSANE for a while, i tried to just invoke the calls myself to test i wasn't really going mad.. this is what i found

```
$.ajax({url:"page"})
            .done(function(r){
                $("#thing").html(r);
            })
            .complete(function(){alert("complete");});
```

This populates the element but does doesn't give me the alernt.. but the below does give me an alert!.. why?

```
$.ajax({url:"page"})
            .done(function(r){
                //$("#thing").html(r);
                alert("done...?");
            })
            .complete(function(){alert("complete");});
```

I get BOTH done and complete alerts..

**UPDATE 1**

For the comment about using "always" instead of "complete". i want to use "load" not "ajax" and, this is the code in jq 1.11.1

```
// Keep a copy of the old load method
var _load = jQuery.fn.load;

/**
 * Load a url into a page
 */
jQuery.fn.load = function( url, params, callback ) {
    if ( typeof url !== "string" && _load ) {
        return _load.apply( this, arguments );
    }

    var selector, response, type,
        self = this,
        off = url.indexOf(" ");

    if ( off >= 0 ) {
        selector = jQuery.trim( url.slice( off, url.length ) );
        url = url.slice( 0, off );
    }

    // If it's a function
    if ( jQuery.isFunction( params ) ) {

        // We assume that it's the callback
        callback = params;
        params = undefined;

    // Otherwise, build a param string
    } else if ( params && typeof params === "object" ) {
        type = "POST";
    }

    // If we have elements to modify, make the request
    if ( self.length > 0 ) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,

            // if "type" variable is undefined, then "GET" method will be used
            type: type,
            dataType: "html",
            data: params
        }).done(function( responseText ) {

            // Save response for use in complete callback
            response = arguments;

            self.html( selector ?

                // If a selector was specified, locate the right elements in a dummy div
                // Exclude scripts to avoid IE 'Permission Denied' errors
                jQuery("<div>").append( jQuery.parseHTML( responseText ) ).find( selector ) :

                // Otherwise use the full result
                responseText );

        }).complete( callback && function( jqXHR, status ) {
            self.each( callback, response || [ jqXHR.responseText, status, jqXHR ] );
        });
    }
    return this;
};
```

notice how it uses "complete"..

Comment: `.complete` doesn't exist in 1.11, it's `.always`. Your first example though should work. Remove `null, `

Comment: this isn't what I do.. this is what the actual jquery "load" method does.. i have no control over this

Comment: I... don't understand your comment.

Comment: i see. .complete wasn't actually removed the same way .success and .error were. **The second half of my comment still applies though.**

Comment: removing null just means it defaults the params param to the callback param, my point here is that if i actually use the "load" code using the ajax function in the same way as jquery source is, it works unless i actually put something into my element. this makes no sense

Comment: FYI - there is no reason to downvote this question, as far as i can see it's valid.

Comment: I can't recreate your problem given your code

Comment: What happens if you intentionally invoke an exception within the "done" code?  Seeing as that's the only difference between the two.  e.g. throw "monkey";

Comment: wow! that's it!!! the "done" call inside jquery source is throwing when it invokes "html".  Even though the html call DOES populate the element, something about the html throws. This means that the complete (always) call never happens! Thanks! 
So all i need to do now is find out exactly why it's throwing on the "html" call (don't really see how it can when the html is being populated)

Comment: Not certain what requirement is ? If possible , can describe details ? Thanks

Comment: If that's the case (an error is happening in `done`) you would be receiving an error in your console.

Comment: good point about the console, this app has a load of errors in the console since i updated the jquery source. this one error read "unexpected token <", i just didnt consider it to be an important one..... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is an odd one.  The HTML coming back from my page is not valid! though it is valid enough to be displayed.  Inside the "load" method the $.parseHTML method is called on append of the responseText/html.  This throws and also returns the html and you will see the html populated in the target element.

What it should probably do is catch this exception and ignore it so that the "complete" method is called every time (so i see this as a bug in jquery).

Comment: If only the jquery promise system was more like the native one, then you could just use .catch. >.<

Comment: Is requirement to catch error in `html` returned from call to `.load()` ?

Comment: I guess you could monkey patch $.parseHTML to catch and ignore any errors that are caused, but then you'd never know if you have invalid html.

Comment: that's the thing i want to dev with full jquery source and deploy the min version, so no monkeys allowed!
I tracked down the issue with the generate page, but yeah my key gripe here is that the "complete" method is not always triggered,  even though that's what's implied.  The ajax might fail, fine, but what if the internal callback (the element population) fails.  Basically though, it is my html which is malformed so i guess it's my own problem